# Iterated integrals and the shuffle product

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, integration, combinatorics, functional-analysis

I cannot understand why the below equality holds, I'm getting lost in the subscripts of the $k's$. This comes from Lyons, Caruana, Lévy (2007), and will provide the quoted full theorem in the "background" part at the bottom:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int \ldots \int_{0<u_1<\ldots<u_r<T} e_{i_1}^*\left(d X_{u_1}\right) \ldots e_{i_r}^*\left(d X_{u_r}\right) \int \ldots \int_{0<v_1<\ldots<v_s<T} e_{j_1}^*\left(d X_{v_1}\right) \ldots e_{j_s}^*\left(d X_{v_s}\right) \\
\quad=& \sum_{\sigma \in \operatorname{Shuffles}(r, s)}\int \ldots \int_{0<w_1<\ldots<w_{r+s}<T} e_{k_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}^*}^*\left(d X_{w_1}\right) \ldots e_{k_{\sigma^{-1}(r+s)}^*}\left(d X_{w_{r+s}}\right) 
\end{aligned}
$$

I will first provide my workings, then I will provide some background on notations and definitions if these could not be deduced.

**Workings:**

$$I =  \int \ldots \int_{0<u_1<\ldots<u_r<T} e_{i_1}^*\left(d X_{u_1}\right) \ldots e_{i_r}^*\left(d X_{u_r}\right) \int \ldots \int_{0<v_1<\ldots<v_s<T} e_{j_1}^*\left(d X_{v_1}\right) \ldots e_{j_s}^*\left(d X_{v_s}\right) 
$$

$$=\left(\int \ldots \int_{0<u_1<\ldots<u_r<T} e_{i_1}^*\left(d X_{u_1}\right) \ldots e_{i_r}^*\left(d X_{u_r}\right) \right) \otimes
\left(\int \ldots \int_{0<v_1<\ldots<v_s<T} e_{j_1}^*\left(d X_{v_1}\right) \ldots e_{j_s}^*\left(d X_{v_s}\right) \right)$$

$$=\left(\int \ldots \int_{0<u_1<\ldots<u_r<T} d X^{i_1}_{u_1} \ldots d X^{i_r}_{u_r}\right) \otimes
 \left(\int \ldots \int_{0<v_1<\ldots<v_s<T}  d X^{j_1}_{v_1} \ldots  d X^{j_s}_{v_s} \right)$$

$$         =\left(\int \ldots \int_{0<u_1<\ldots<u_r<T} \dot{X}^{i_1}_{u_1} \otimes\ldots \otimes\dot{X}^{i_r}_{u_r} du_1 \ldots du_r \right)\otimes \left(\int \ldots \int_{0<v_1<\ldots<v_s<T}  \dot{X}^{j_1}_{v_1} \otimes\ldots \otimes \dot{X}^{j_s}_{v_s} dv_1 \ldots dv_r  \right)$$

$$ =\int \ldots \int_{\{0<u_1<\ldots<u_r<T\} \cap \{ 0<v_1<\ldots<v_s<T  \}} \dot{X}^{i_1}_{u_1} \otimes\ldots \otimes\dot{X}^{i_r}_{u_r} \otimes \dot{X}^{j_1}_{v_1} \otimes\ldots \otimes \dot{X}^{j_s}_{v_s} du_1 \ldots du_r dv_1 \ldots dv_r $$

$$=\int \ldots \int_{\{0<w_1<\ldots<w_r<T\} \cap \{ 0<w_{r+1}<\ldots<w_{r+s}<T  \}} \dot{X}^{i_1}_{w_1} \otimes\ldots \otimes\dot{X}^{i_r}_{w_r} \otimes \dot{X}^{j_1}_{w_{r+1}} \otimes\ldots \otimes \dot{X}^{j_s}_{w_{r+s}} dw_1 \ldots dw_r dw_{r+1} \ldots dw_{r+s} $$

$$= \sum_{\sigma \in \text{Shuffles}(r,s)} \int \ldots \int_{ 0<w_{\sigma(1)}< \ldots<w_{\sigma(r+s)}<T  } \dot{X}^{i_1}_{w_1} \otimes\ldots \otimes\dot{X}^{i_r}_{w_r} \otimes \dot{X}^{j_1}_{w_{r+1}} \otimes\ldots \otimes \dot{X}^{j_s}_{w_{r+s}} dw_1 \ldots dw_r dw_{r+1} \ldots dw_{r+s} 
$$

Now set $\tilde{w} := w \circ \sigma$, since $\sigma$ is a bijection $ w  =  \tilde{w} \circ\sigma^{-1}$ and the order of the $dw$'s is irrelevant

$$= \sum_{\sigma \in \text{Shuffles}(r,s)} \int \ldots \int_{ 0<\tilde{w}_1<\ldots<\tilde{w}_{r+s}<T  } 
 \dot{X}^{i_1}_{\tilde{w} _{\sigma^{-1}(1)}} \otimes\ldots \otimes\dot{X}^{i_r}_{\tilde{w} _{\sigma^{-1}(r)}} \otimes \dot{X}^{j_1}_{\tilde{w} _{\sigma^{-1}(r+1)}} \otimes\ldots \otimes \dot{X}^{j_s}_{\tilde{w} _{\sigma^{-1}(r+s)}} d\tilde{w}_1 \ldots d\tilde{w}_r d\tilde{w}_{r+1} \ldots d\tilde{w}_{r+s} 
$$

And I'm stuck here...

**Background:**

*Theorem 2.15. The linear forms on $T((E))$ induced by $T\left(E^*\right)$, when restricted to the range $S\left(\mathcal{V}^p([0, T], E)\right)$ of the signature, form an algebra of realvalued functions.
Proof. By linearity, it is sufficient to prove the result when $\mathbf{e}^*=e_I^*$ and $\mathbf{f}^*=e_J^*$ for some finite words $I=\left(i_1, \ldots, i_r\right)$ and $J=\left(j_1, \ldots, j_s\right)$. Once two such words are fixed, set $\left(k_1, \ldots, k_{r+s}\right)=\left(i_1, \ldots, i_r, j_1, \ldots, j_s\right)$. Now we say that a permutation $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_{r+s}$ is a shuffle of $\{1, \ldots, r\}$ and $\{r+1, \ldots, r+s\}$ if $\sigma(1)<\ldots<\sigma(r)$ and $\sigma(r+1)<\ldots<\sigma(s)$. We write $\sigma \in \operatorname{Shuffles}(r, s)$.
Let $X:[0, T] \longrightarrow E$ be a path with bounded variation. Then $\varphi_I(X) \varphi_J(X)$ is equal to
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int \ldots \int_{0<u_1<\ldots<u_r<T} e_{i_1}^*\left(d X_{u_1}\right) \ldots e_{i_r}^*\left(d X_{u_r}\right) \int \ldots \int_{0<v_1<\ldots<v_s<T} e_{j_1}^*\left(d X_{v_1}\right) \ldots e_{j_s}^*\left(d X_{v_s}\right) \\
\quad=& \sum_{\sigma \in \operatorname{Shuffles}(r, s)}\int \ldots \int_{0<w_1<\ldots<w_{r+s}<T} e_{k_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}^*}^*\left(d X_{w_1}\right) \ldots e_{k_{\sigma^{-1}(r+s)}^*}\left(d X_{w_{r+s}}\right) 
\end{aligned}
$$*

$X$ is a path defined on a real interval taking values on a finite dimensional vector space with basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^d$. I will assume that $X$ is Lipschitz continuous for simplicity.  I interpret $e^*_{m}(dX_{u_1}):=dX^m_{u_1}$ where $X^m_{(\cdot)}$ is the $m$-th coordinate of $X$. I also understand that these iterated integrals are defined through tensor products, in the sense that, when $X$ is Lipschitz:

$$
\int_s^t\int_{s}^{u_2}dX_{u_1}dX_{u_2}:=  \int_s^t\int_{s}^{u_2}\dot{X}_{u_1}\otimes\dot{X}_{u_2}du_1du_2.
$$

When I compute this, I get that the LHS is equal to the integral over $0<w_1<\ldots<w_{r+s}<T$ of the $dX^{k_j}_{w_{\sigma^{-1}(j)}}$. What is my mistake?

**EDIT**:

I made a mistake, as Rhys pointed out, when claiming that the LHS of my equality is equal to

$$ \begin{gathered}
\sum_{\sigma \in \operatorname{Shuffles}(r, s)} \int \ldots \int_{R:= \{0<w_{\sigma(1)}<\ldots<w_{\sigma(r+s)}<T\} } \dot{X}_{w_1}^{i_1} \otimes \ldots \otimes \dot{X}_{w_r}^{i_r} \otimes \dot{X}_{w_{r+1}}^{j_1} \otimes \ldots \otimes \dot{X}_{w_{r+s}}^{j_s} d w_1 \\
\ldots d w_r d w_{r+1} \ldots d w_{r+s},
\end{gathered}$$

when in fact $R:= \{0<w_{\sigma^{-1} (1)}<\ldots<w_{\sigma^{-1} (r+s)}<T\}$. So that I follow his argument until he concludes the LHS of my equality is equal to:

$$= \sum_{\sigma \in \text{Shuffles}(r,s)} \int_{0< w_1 < \dots < w_{r+s} < T} dX_{{w}_{\sigma(1)}}^{k_1} \dots dX_{{w}_{\sigma(r+s)}}^{k_{r+s}}.$$

Then, he uses some form of "rough" Fubini which I can't see why it should hold. To see where "rough" Fubini is applied explicitly, consider the example where $r=s=3$ and the particular term in $\sum_{\text{Shuffles}(3,3)}$ where $\sigma$ is given by $\sigma(1)=1,\sigma(2)=3,\sigma(3)=5, \sigma(4)=2, \sigma(5)=4,$ and $\sigma(6)=6$. Then, with "rough" Fubini being applied where I put $(*)$, we would indeed get the desired expression:

$$\int\ldots \int dX^{k_1}_{w_{\sigma(1)}}dX^{k_2}_{w_{\sigma(2)}}dX^{k_3}_{w_{\sigma(3)}}dX^{k_4}_{w_{\sigma(4)}}dX^{k_5}_{w_{\sigma(5)}}dX^{k_6}_{w_{\sigma(6)}}
\\=   \int\ldots \int dX^{k_1}_{w_{1}}dX^{k_2}_{w_{3}}dX^{k_3}_{w_{5}}dX^{k_4}_{w_{2}}dX^{k_5}_{w_{4}}dX^{k_6}_{w_{6}}
\\\stackrel{(*)}{=} \int\ldots \int
 dX^{k_1}_{w_{1}} dX^{k_4}_{w_{2}} dX^{k_2}_{w_{3}}  dX^{k_5}_{w_{4}}
dX^{k_3}_{w_{5}}dX^{k_6}_{w_{6}}
$$
$$\\= \int\ldots \int dX^{k_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}}_{w_{1}} dX^{ k_{\sigma^{-1}(2)}}_{w_{2}} dX^{ k_{\sigma^{-1}(3)}}_{w_{3}}  dX^{ k_{\sigma^{-1}(4)}}_{w_{4}}dX^{ k_{\sigma^{-1}(5)}}_{w_{5}}dX^{ k_{\sigma^{-1}(6)}}_{w_{6}}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Other than what Rhys pointed out regarding permutations and inverses, there is no tensor product (or if you like the tensor product of scalars is just multiplication by scalars).

**Answer**

The claim is as follows. Let $V$ be finite-dimensional and take $T>0$. Assume $X:[0,T]\to  V$ is a path of finite $p$-variation for some $p\in [1,2)$. Let $\{e_j\}_{j=1}^{d}$ be a basis of $V$ and define $\int e^*_j(dX_u) := \int dX^j_u$ where $X^j$ denotes the $j$-th component of $X$ and $\int dX^j_u$ is to be understood in the Young, or Riemann-Stieltjes, sense (more details on this later). Then it follows that:

$$
\int \ldots \int_{0<u_1<\ldots<u_r<T} e_{i_1}^*\left(d X_{u_1}\right) \ldots e_{i_r}^*\left(d X_{u_r}\right) \int \ldots \int_{0<v_1<\ldots<v_s<T} e_{j_1}^*\left(d X_{v_1}\right) \ldots e_{j_s}^*\left(d X_{v_s}\right)
$$
$$
= \int \ldots \int_{0<u_1<\ldots<u_r<T}  dX^{i_1}_{u_1} \ldots dX^{i_r}_{u_r}
 \int \ldots \int_{0<v_1<\ldots<v_s<T}  dX^{j_1}_{v_1} \ldots dX^{j_s}_{v_s} 
$$
$$
= \sum_{\sigma \in \operatorname{Shuffles}(r, s)}\int \ldots \int_{0<w_1<\ldots<w_{r+s}<T}  d X^{k_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}}_{w_1}  \ldots d X^{k_{\sigma^{-1}(r+s)}}_{w_{r+s}} 
$$
$$
= \sum_{\sigma \in \operatorname{Shuffles}(r, s)}\int \ldots \int_{0<w_1<\ldots<w_{r+s}<T} e^*_{k_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}}\left(d X_{w_1}\right) \ldots e^*_{k_{\sigma^{-1}(r+s)}}\left(d X_{w_{r+s}}\right)
$$

The proof goes like this. We would like to start by assuming that $X$ has finite 1-variation (i.e., bounded variation). Assume, further, that $X$ is Lipschitz continuous for simplicity, which is a little bit stronger than $X$ having finite $1$-variation.

$$I =  \int \ldots \int_{0<u_1<\ldots<u_r<T} e_{i_1}^*\left(d X_{u_1}\right) \ldots e_{i_r}^*\left(d X_{u_r}\right) \int \ldots \int_{0<v_1<\ldots<v_s<T} e_{j_1}^*\left(d X_{v_1}\right) \ldots e_{j_s}^*\left(d X_{v_s}\right) 
$$

$$=\left(\int \ldots \int_{0<u_1<\ldots<u_r<T} e_{i_1}^*\left(d X_{u_1}\right) \ldots e_{i_r}^*\left(d X_{u_r}\right) \right) \cdot
\left(\int \ldots \int_{0<v_1<\ldots<v_s<T} e_{j_1}^*\left(d X_{v_1}\right) \ldots e_{j_s}^*\left(d X_{v_s}\right) \right)$$

$$=\left(\int \ldots \int_{0<u_1<\ldots<u_r<T} d X^{i_1}_{u_1} \ldots d X^{i_r}_{u_r}\right) \cdot
 \left(\int \ldots \int_{0<v_1<\ldots<v_s<T}  d X^{j_1}_{v_1} \ldots  d X^{j_s}_{v_s} \right)$$

$$         =\left(\int \ldots \int_{0<u_1<\ldots<u_r<T} \dot{X}^{i_1}_{u_1} \ldots\dot{X}^{i_r}_{u_r} du_1 \ldots du_r \right)\cdot \left(\int \ldots \int_{0<v_1<\ldots<v_s<T}  \dot{X}^{j_1}_{v_1} \ldots \dot{X}^{j_s}_{v_s} dv_1 \ldots dv_r  \right)$$

$$ =\int \ldots \int_{\{0<u_1<\ldots<u_r<T\} \cap \{ 0<v_1<\ldots<v_s<T  \}} \dot{X}^{i_1}_{u_1} \ldots\dot{X}^{i_r}_{u_r} \cdot \dot{X}^{j_1}_{v_1} \ldots \dot{X}^{j_s}_{v_s} du_1 \ldots du_r dv_1 \ldots dv_r $$

$$=\int \ldots \int_{\{0<w_1<\ldots<w_r<T\} \cap \{ 0<w_{r+1}<\ldots<w_{r+s}<T  \}} \dot{X}^{i_1}_{w_1} \ldots\dot{X}^{i_r}_{w_r} \cdot \dot{X}^{j_1}_{w_{r+1}} \ldots \dot{X}^{j_s}_{w_{r+s}} dw_1 \ldots dw_r dw_{r+1} \ldots dw_{r+s} $$

$$= \sum_{\sigma \in \text{Shuffles}(r,s)} \int \ldots \int_{ 0<w_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}< \ldots<w_{\sigma^{-1}(r+s)}<T } \dot{X}^{i_1}_{w_1} \ldots\dot{X}^{i_r}_{w_r} \cdot \dot{X}^{j_1}_{w_{r+1}} \ldots \dot{X}^{j_s}_{w_{r+s}} dw_1 \ldots dw_r dw_{r+1} \ldots dw_{r+s} 
$$

Now set $\tilde{w} := w \circ \sigma^{-1}$, then  $ w  =  \tilde{w} \circ\sigma$ and we have

$$I = \sum_{\sigma \in \text{Shuffles}(r,s)} \int \ldots \int_{ 0<\tilde{w}_1<\ldots<\tilde{w}_{r+s}<T  } 
 \dot{X}^{i_1}_{\tilde{w} _{\sigma^(1)}} \ldots\dot{X}^{i_r}_{\tilde{w} _{\sigma(r)}} \cdot \dot{X}^{j_1}_{\tilde{w} _{\sigma(r+1)}} \ldots \dot{X}^{j_s}_{\tilde{w} _{\sigma(r+s)}} d\tilde{w}_1 \ldots d\tilde{w}_r d\tilde{w}_{r+1} \ldots d\tilde{w}_{r+s} 
$$ $$=  \sum_{\sigma \in \text{Shuffles}(r,s
)} \int \ldots \int_{ 0<\tilde{w}_1<\ldots<\tilde{w}_{r+s}<T  } 
 \dot{X}^{k_1}_{\tilde{w} _{\sigma^(1)}} \ldots\dot{X}^{k_r}_{\tilde{w} _{\sigma(r)}} \cdot \dot{X}^{k_{r+1}}_{\tilde{w} _{\sigma(r+1)}} \ldots \dot{X}^{k_{r+s}}_{\tilde{w} _{\sigma(r+s)}} d\tilde{w}_1 \ldots d\tilde{w}_r d\tilde{w}_{r+1} \ldots d\tilde{w}_{r+s}
 $$

By Fubini's theorem, the order of the $d\tilde{w}$'s is irrelevant. Multiplication of scalars is certainly commutative (remember $X_u = \sum_{\ell=1}^d X^\ell_u e^\ell$ where $X^\ell_u$ are scalar-valued paths). Observe, although it takes a little convincing, that if I rearrange the $\dot{X}^{k_m}_{\tilde{w}_{\sigma(m)}}$ so that the subscripts are in order, then the superscripts will bear $\sigma^{-1}$'s. A simple example with e.g. $r=2, s=3$ and any fixed shuffle permutation $\sigma\in$ Shuffles$(2,3)$ should convince the reader. With this, we conclude that:

$$I = \sum_{\sigma \in \text{Shuffles}(r,s
)} \int \ldots \int_{ 0<\tilde{w}_1<\ldots<\tilde{w}_{r+s}<T  } 
 \dot{X}^{k_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}}_{\tilde{w}_{1}} \ldots\dot{X}^{k_{\sigma^{-1}(r)}}_{\tilde{w}_r } \cdot \dot{X}^{k_{\sigma^{-1}(r+1)}}_{\tilde{w}_{r+1} } \ldots \dot{X}^{k_{\sigma^{-1}({r+s})}}_{\tilde{w}_{r+s} } d\tilde{w}_1 \ldots d\tilde{w}_r d\tilde{w}_{r+1} \ldots d\tilde{w}_{r+s}  $$

If has bounded variation but is not Lipschitz continuous, then the integrals make sense as Riemann Stieltjes integrals and Fubini is still valid for them. So the argument is essentially the same, but for working with $dX^j_u$ as opposed to $\dot{X^j}_u du$. If $X$ has finite $p$-variation for $p>1$, take a sequence of piece-wise linear paths which converge in $p'$-variation and everything is continuous in the induced topology (could give a little more detail on this but I am in a rush right now)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly where you made a mistake without seeing your computations. Let me instead provide an argument for the equality and hopefully that will either help you spot your own error or you can point to the exact step in the argument you do not follow and maybe I can then say more.

We can write the left hand side as
$$\int_{A} dX_{\bar{w}_1}^{k_1} \dots dX_{\bar{w}_{r+s}}^{k_{r+s}}$$
where $A = \{\bar{w}: 0< \bar{w}_1 < \dots < \bar{w}_r < T, 0 < \bar{w}_{r+1} < \dots < \bar{w}_{r+s} < T\}$. Then we write
$$A = \bigcup_{\sigma \in \text{Shuffles}(r,s)} \{\bar{w}: 0 < \bar{w}_{\sigma^{-1}(1)} < \dots < \bar{w}_{\sigma^{-1}(r+s)} < T\}$$
so that
$$\int_{A} dX_{\bar{w}_1}^{k_1} \dots dX_{\bar{w}_{r+s}}^{k_{r+s}} = \sum_{\sigma \in \text{Shuffles}(r,s)} \int_{0< \bar{w}_{\sigma^{-1}(1)} < \dots < \bar{w}_{\sigma^{-1}(r+s)} < T} dX_{\bar{w}_1}^{k_1} \dots dX_{\bar{w}_{r+s}}^{k_{r+s}}.$$

Set $w_i = \bar{w}_{\sigma^{-1}(i)}$ and note that $\bar{w}_i = w_{\sigma(i)}$. Then
$$\sum_{\sigma \in \text{Shuffles}(r,s)} \int_{0< \bar{w}_{\sigma^{-1}(1)} < \dots \bar{w}_{\sigma^{-1}(r+s)} < T} dX_{\bar{w}_1}^{k_1} \dots dX_{\bar{w}_{r+s}}^{k_{r+s}} = \sum_{\sigma \in \text{Shuffles}(r,s)} \int_{0< w_1 < \dots < w_{r+s} < T} dX_{{w}_{\sigma(1)}}^{k_1} \dots dX_{{w}_{\sigma(r+s)}}^{k_{r+s}}.$$

By Fubini, since $\sigma$ is a permutation, integrating with respect to $dX_{{w}_{\sigma(1)}}^{k_1} \dots dX_{{w}_{\sigma(r+s)}}^{k_{r+s}}$ is the same as integrating with respect to $dX_{w_1}^{k_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}} \dots dX_{w_{r+s}}^{k_{\sigma^{-1}(r+s)}}$ which is what we wanted.

---

Edit: You added your calculation whilst I wrote this and I posted before I saw that. I will leave the above intact and just note that the difference is that when decomposing my set $A$ as a union over $(r,s)$-shuffles, following your argument would put $\sigma$ instead of $\sigma^{-1}$ in the right hand side.

To see that this is incorrect, consider the case $r = s = 3$. Then one valid region in the original integral is $0 < w_1 < w_4 < w_2 < w_5 < w_3 < w_6 < T$. However, since for any (3,3)-shuffle $\sigma$, $\sigma(1) < \sigma(2) < \sigma(3)$; there is no $\sigma$ such that this region is of the form $0 < w_{\sigma(1)} < \dots < w_{\sigma(6)} < T$.

Comment: Hi Rhys, thank you very much for your detailed answer. It is exciting to hear from someone with much experience in rough analysis. I have two questions: first of all, what version of (rough) Fubini do you apply to, say, 

$$ \int_{s<u_1<u_2<t}dX_{u_1} dX_{u_2}$$

While Lyons' book doesn't discuss any such rough Fubini theorems *per se*, I have just found one in (an exercise) of Friz and Hairer (2014) which I will copy-paste below. Indeed, this is why I considered the Lipschitz continuous case, when I write:

Comment: ...$$ \int_{s<u_1<u_2<t}dX_1 dX_2 =  \int_{s<u_1<u_2<t}\dot{X}_{u_1} \otimes \dot{X}_{u_2}du_1du_2,$$

it would seem like, interpreting now this integral as a standard Riemann-Stieltjes integral, Fubini would give us:

$$ \int_{s<u_1<u_2<t}\dot{X}_{u_1} \otimes \dot{X}_{u_2}du_1du_2 =
 \int_s^t\int_s^{u_2}\dot{X}_{u_1} \otimes \dot{X}_{u_2}du_1du_2 =
 \int_s^{t}\int_{u_1}^t\dot{X}_{u_1} \otimes \dot{X}_{u_2}du_2 du_1$$

Since the tensor product is non-commutative, we cannot have that $$\dot{X}_{u_1} \otimes \dot{X}_{u_2} = \dot{X}_{u_2} \otimes \dot{X}_{u_1}$$...

Comment: ...to recover something like $$ \int_s^{t}\int_{u_1}^t\dot{X}_{u_1} \otimes \dot{X}_{u_2}du_2 du_1 =  \int_s^{t}\int_{u_1}^t\dot{X}_{u_2} \otimes \dot{X}_{u_1}du_2 du_1 = 
\int_s^{t}\int_{u_1}^t dX_{u_2} dX_{u_1}= \int_{s<u_1<u_2<t}dX_{u_2} dX_{u_1}$$.

The exercise I mentioned from Friz and Hairer says:

Comment: 4.11 (b) Let now $\mathbf{X}=(X, \mathbb{X}) \in \mathscr{C}^\alpha([0, T])$ for some $\alpha>1 / 3$, and $\left(Y, Y^{\prime}\right),\left(\tilde{Y}, \tilde{Y}^{\prime}\right) \in$ $\mathscr{D}_X^{2 \alpha}$. Set $Z_{s, t}:=Y_s \otimes Y_t$. Show that
$$
\int_0^T \int_0^t Z_{s, t} d \mathbf{X}_s d \mathbf{X}_t=\int_0^T \int_s^T Z_{s, t} d \mathbf{X}_t d \mathbf{X}_s+\int_0^T Z_{t, t} d[\mathbf{X}]_t,
$$
where the final integral is a Young integral against $[\mathbf{X}] \in \mathcal{C}^{2 \alpha}$, the bracket introduced in Exercise 2.11.

Comment: In a nutshell, I can't see Fubini being valid without a correction term. The second question is about there not being a $3$-$3$ shuffle $\sigma$ such that:

$$\{w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4,w_5,w_6\} =:S \stackrel{\text{Composing with } \sigma}{\to}\{w_1,w_4,w_2,w_5,w_3,w_6\} =: P.$$

Defining $A:=\{w: 0< w_1 <w_2 <w_3<t, 0< w_4 <w_5 <w_6<t\}$ we have that $P\in A$. We say that $\sigma \in \text{Shuffles}(3,3)\subset \text{Permutations}(6)$ if $\sigma: \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\to \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is a bijection s.t., as you said, $\sigma(1)<\sigma(2)<\sigma(3)$ and $\sigma(4)<\sigma(5)<\sigma(6)$. [...]

Comment: [...] But notice that, to get $P$, our $\sigma$ is such that $\sigma(1) = 1 < \sigma(2) = 3 < \sigma(3) = 5$. Hence, $\sigma(S):= \{w_{\sigma(1)},w_{\sigma(2)}, w_{\sigma(3)},w_{\sigma(4)},w_{\sigma(5)},w_{\sigma(6)} \}= P$

Comment: @MartinGeller My interests go in the direction of singular SPDE rather than rough path so I am no expert on these issues. My impression was that when dealing with paths of finite $p$-variation for $p \in [1,2)$ there was always this idea of treating first the case $p = 1$ where things are nice (and a good version of Fubini should hold) and then treating the case $p > 1$ by truncating the signature and approximating the path in a slightly stronger topology than the $p$-var one by paths of finite $1$ variation. I think Lyons, Levy, Caruana might have some details?

Comment: Your comments on the permutation confuse me though. You write $P := \{w_1, w_4, w_2, w_5, w_3, w_6\}$ (which I guess I should think of as an ordered set) and then say that for a $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(1) = 1, \sigma(2) = 3, \sigma(3) = 5\}$ we get that $P = \{w_{\sigma(1)},w_{\sigma(2)}, w_{\sigma(3)},w_{\sigma(4)},w_{\sigma(5)},w_{\sigma(6)} \} = \{w_1, w_3, w_5, w_{\sigma(4)},w_{\sigma(5)},w_{\sigma(6)}\}$. This seems incorrect.

Comment: The natural definition of $\sigma(S)$ here is the one that moves the $k$-th element of the ordered set $S$ to the $\sigma(k)$-th spot. This is not the same as $\{w_{\sigma(1)},w_{\sigma(2)}, w_{\sigma(3)},w_{\sigma(4)},w_{\sigma(5)},w_{\sigma(6)} \}$. It is in fact equal to $\{w_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},w_{\sigma^{-1}(2)}, w_{\sigma^{-1}(3)},w_{\sigma^{-1}(4)},w_{\sigma^{-1}(5)},w_{\sigma^{-1}(6)} \}$

Comment: Yes, I completely missed the mark there. It makes sense now